# What's a good free VPN for Ubuntu?

Tags: security, vpn

I travel a lot and am always using open wifis anymore. I know Ubuntu is a pretty sturdy OS with some good security, but I still want to be safe out and about. However, I've never used a VPN under Ubuntu. Haven't a clue on how to set one up or even what's available. I'm looking for one that doesn't cost anything, any solutions?

I especially don't know how to set up one under 17.10, a lot's changed.

Comment: Install `TOR` and configure your system to pass all traffic through the tor port

Comment: Running tor provides good anonymity. It does, however, not provide good security, as any operator of the exit node can read all your traffic. Use tor for anonymity, *never* for security.

Comment: tor is not a vpn

Comment: Goto https://www.vpnbook.com/#openvpn, and download US1. Extract the zip file. Then, in that directory, execute the following:
```sudo apt-get -y install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome;
sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file vpnbook-us1-udp25000.ovpn;
nmcli connection modify vpnbook-us1-udp25000 +vpn.data username=vpnbook;
nmcli connection modify vpnbook-us1-udp25000 +vpn.data password-flags=0;
nmcli connection modify vpnbook-us1-udp25000 +vpn.secrets password=5m1c3f```, but replacing "5m1c3f" with the password at that link. Now, you're good to go

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Check **OpenVPN**, it's an open source virtual private network. Step by step guide provided by the Official Ubuntu Documentation on this link:
[OpenVPN](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/openvpn.html)

If this is too complicated there is an easier way to set a simple VPN.

1. Open **Terminal** and type`sudo apt-get install openvpn network-manager-openvpn network-manager-openvpn-gnome` then enter: `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`.
2. Go to: https://www.vpnbook.com/ and download the package you want under 'OpenVPN'. Make sure to save the user and password you're given as you'll later need it.[image: 2]]
3. Extract. You'll have four or maybe more different files. **Stick with one** and only one and discard the others.[image]
4. Create 3 new files: *certificate.crt*, *ca.crt*, and *key.key*. Open the *.opvn* you downloaded and copy the text between **< ca >** and **< /ca >** into your *ca.crt*. Do the same with your other files: copy everything under **< cert >** and over **< /cert >** into *certificate.crt*; and everything between **< key >** and **< /key >** into *key.key*.[image]
5. Now go to *Network*  in *Settings* and add a new VPN Network
6. In the configuration window: name it whatever you want. **Gateway**: copy the address given in the third line of the *.ovpn* file just after *remote* and before the separate number which is the port number. Depending on what file you chose, you'll have different gateways/port numbers.
   [image]
7. Choose *Password with Certificates (LTS)* in **Authentication / Type** and copy and paste the user and password you were given on the site (Step 2). **User Certificate** is your *certificate.crt*, **CA Certificate** is your *ca.crt*, and **Private Key** is your *key.key* file.
   [image]
8. Click **Advanced...**, select the options that you see in this image. **Use custom gateway port** is the number that you have in your *.ovpn* file (Step 6). Now go to the **Security** tab and set **Cipher** to *AES-128-CBC* 
   [image]
9. Done. If your connection doesn't establish right away and keeps disconnecting, change the VPN password setting to *Store the password for all users.*

**Source**: transcript of [How to Establish An OpenVPN Connection FREE in Ubuntu-15.10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tcx2-EkYYDg)

update for UBUNTU 18.04:
in the Advance settings (step 8) after checking the option:
Use LZO data compression you need to choose "Yes" instead of "Adaptive"

Comment: Ok, I installed OpenVPN and I have the option for OpenVPN under the VPN settings in settings. What do I enter into these fields to get it to work? I have the .keys and .crts and whatnot generated from following the directions.

Comment: Just what do I plug where?

Comment: That guide doesn't rely on the Ubuntu Network Configuration GUI based program. Every configuration is done via command line.  I'll be adding a step-by-step with what worked for me.

Comment: A rather large percentage of these instructions could simply be reduced to `sudo nmcli connection import type openvpn file /path/to/your.ovpn`

Comment: Can you please update it to 18.04? There's no option to use a key for authentication, and overall some steps are different or missing

Comment: @LucasBustamante Sorry, but I'm not familiar with Ubuntu anymore. My computer was destroyed in a flood that took most of my belongings.

Comment: In the higher versions of Ubuntu, there is an option to import `.ovpn`, so you don't need to type details manually.

Answer (score 3):

Check protonvpn.com, it's free but the traffic is capped.

https://protonvpn.com/support/linux-vpn-setup/

Or use the Tor-Browser and use a fast exit node. Not NSA safe, but you can watch Youtube in 1080p and your ISP doesn't know what you browse/watch. Look for a fast exit node @ http://torstatus.blutmagie.de/ and write it into the TORRC file.

Like this:

```
ExitNodes 100.100.194.53,112.112.89.53
StrictNodes 1
```

https://www.torproject.org/docs/tor-manual.html.en

If that's too complicated or slow for your needs, check https://www.privacytools.io/#vpn for cheap VPNs.

Answer (score 3):

I will prefer `Tor` to you as it will help you browse anonymously.

Below are the steps to use `Tor` without too much configurations

**Install Tor**

```
sudo apt-get install tor
```

No configuration is needed for `tor`, we will use the default one.

**Install proxychains**

```
sudo apt-get install proxychains
```

This tool allows specified application to pass all traffic of the application through the proxy server.

**Next**, we will add tor proxy url to `proxychains.conf`

```
echo "socks5    127.0.0.1 9050" >> /etc/proxychains.conf
```

In Ubuntu, the location of `proxychains.conf` can be different.

You're done configuring the tools. Use it this way,

**1st Terminal**

```
$ tor
```

Let it run, don't close it

**2nd Terminal**

```
$ proxychains firefox
```

or

```
$ proxychains bash
$ firefox
```

Note that few programs like `google-chrome` and `chromium` might not work with `proxychains` because of their security sandbox.

For **chromium**,

```
$ chromium --proxy-server="socks5://127.0.0.1:9050"
```

Comment: tor is not a vpn and should not be confused with one.