# Setting up VPNBook VPN

Tags: vpn

I am on Ubuntu 18.04 and I would like to set up a VPN.

I found the thread [What's a good free VPN for Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975827/whats-a-good-free-vpn-for-ubuntu) and did the option suggested by pvaesrtdoe, [the top answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/975829/250300).

After, I tried turning on the VPN, which, after ~30 seconds, resulted in a connection failed message from Ubuntu.

Next, I tried as [suggested by Gannet in this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1073697/setting-up-vpnbook-pvn/1073698#1073698).  I entered the command line (after cd'ing the correct directory and getting the file name and login info):

```
sudo openvpn vpn_file.ovpn
```

This is the output I got after inputting the requested info (received from VPNBook):

```
Sun Sep  9 17:24:09 2018 WARNING: No server certificate verification method has been enabled.  See http://openvpn.net/howto.html#mitm for more info.
Sun Sep  9 17:24:09 2018 NOTE: --fast-io is disabled since we are not using UDP
Sun Sep  9 17:24:09 2018 TCP/UDP: Preserving recently used remote address: [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:80
Sun Sep  9 17:24:09 2018 Socket Buffers: R=[87380->87380] S=[16384->16384]
Sun Sep  9 17:24:09 2018 Attempting to establish TCP connection with [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:80 [nonblock]
Sun Sep  9 17:24:10 2018 TCP: connect to [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:80 failed: Connection refused
Sun Sep  9 17:24:10 2018 SIGUSR1[connection failed(soft),init_instance] received, process restarting
Sun Sep  9 17:24:10 2018 Restart pause, 5 second(s)
```

How does one set up VPNBook on Ubuntu 18.04?

Comment: `TCP: connect to [AF_INET]176.126.237.217:80 failed: Connection refused` – Looks like the VPN server refuses the connection. Please review the server address and port and make sure that there really is a VPN service running. (I’ll write a proper answer if somebody notifies me when this question reopened.)

Answer (score 1):

Just download any of openvpn zips from vpnbook web page. Unpack it. Run in terminal the following: `sudo openvpn vpn_file.ovpn` and enter the password on ask. That's it.

Comment: I edit my question after trying out the method

Comment: I shows Connection refused from another side. Is your vpn-file freshly downloaded from vpnbook site?