# OpenVPN blocking Thunderbird Email

Tags: email, openvpn, ufw

I am a OpenVPN noobie.  My question is straight forward, how do I get email (thunderbird, ports 993,465,587) to work with openvpn?

On my Ubuntu 18.04, I set-up UFW rules allowing my email to go in and out. When I turn openvpn client off, but keep UFW enabled, email works correctly.  The moment I activate openvpn client all emails stop (connection time outs) outgoing/incoming.

I used [these](https://askubuntu.com/questions/975827/whats-a-good-free-vpn-for-ubuntu) instructions to configure OpenVPN. (using vpnbook)

I used [these](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UFWcliff) instructions to configure UFW

Are there any other configurations I need to make to get email working? Or does OpenVPN outright block / disallow email imap/smtp?

Comment: vpnbook is a free VPN provider and almost certainly blocks the standard email ports to avoid the whole issue with spammers using their services. I checked and they say `we do not block any ports` but I strongly suspect they do. If I were running a free VPN site, I'd definitely block the email ports.

Comment: Seems pointless to advertise, "no blocking ports", then block ports... Wastes a lot of people time.  But that does seem to be the case because I can't find anything else to configure.  It pointless to offer a vpn that doesn't allow users to check email...  :-(

Comment: I'd check with them to see if they're blocked. I'd *personally* block them on a free VPN to avoid abuse issues - or maybe make it an up-sell option to get people to pay. But, that's just me. Your best choice, that I can think of, would be to contact them to see if they're blocking those ports.

Comment: Already dropped them a message... I honestly wouldn't have minded paying for it, but blocking ports when you advertise you don't just seems dirty... spend the cash elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, being less ticked about a free service... I found a great use case for a VPN with ports blocked... it's called KODI  ...watching 100% legal content with KODI  ;-) , means that I am not checking my email...